# Google chrome shows error when I download file

Tags: php, google-chrome

I am using **Google Chrome** to open my web page.

When I download a file, I get:

> ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

After that, I go to see my code, I have a line as below:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$downloadFileName);
```

Can someone help me so that I can download the file?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose filename in double quotes:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$downloadFileName.'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know PHP's grammer.
Assuming your code's syntax is right, I guess you may try:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"'.$downloadFileName.'\"');
```

You'll need double quotes around the filename.